# Showing Morning, afternoon, evening, night message based on Time in java

Tags: java, android, date, time

### What i am trying to do::

**Show message based on**

- Good morning  (12am-12pm)
- Good after noon (12pm -4pm)
- Good evening (4pm to 9pm)
- Good night ( 9pm to 6am)

---

### CODE::

I used 24-hr format to get this logic

```
private void getTimeFromAndroid() {
        Date dt = new Date();
        int hours = dt.getHours();
        int min = dt.getMinutes();

        if(hours>=1 || hours<=12){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good Morning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(hours>=12 || hours<=16){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good Afternoon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(hours>=16 || hours<=21){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good Evening", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(hours>=21 || hours<=24){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good Night", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

---

### Question:

- Is this this best way of doing it, If no which is the best way

Comment: @Devrath off-topic note, should'nt it be AND && , you are using OR || which will result all cases (hours >= 1) fall in Good Morning case?

Comment: You should know, that the hours are in range between `0` and `23`: [`getHours()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getHours%28%29).

Comment: @Devrath I've updated the answer to take into account 12:59.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You should be doing something like:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

if(timeOfDay >= 0 && timeOfDay < 12){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Good Morning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
}else if(timeOfDay >= 12 && timeOfDay < 16){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Good Afternoon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else if(timeOfDay >= 16 && timeOfDay < 21){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Good Evening", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else if(timeOfDay >= 21 && timeOfDay < 24){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Good Night", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I would add an `else` case at the bottom to catch any unexpected value ([defensive programming](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming)).

Comment: @BasilBourque Exactly. Even if it notifies your support team of a strange edge case. The key is to not let this crash the app since it's not mission critical.

Comment: getInstance(); need android api 24.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 31):

For anyone who is looking for the latest **Kotlin** syntax for @SMA's answer, here is the helper function :

```
fun getGreetingMessage():String{
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    val timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)

    return when (timeOfDay) {
           in 0..11 -> "Good Morning"
           in 12..15 -> "Good Afternoon"
           in 16..20 -> "Good Evening"
           in 21..23 -> "Good Night"
           else -> "Hello"
      }
    }
```

Comment: ..or use `in 0 until 12`, `in 12 until 16` and so on if you prefer/agreed to use ranges with exclusive ends.

Answer (score 7):

I would shorten your `if/elseif` statement to:

```
String greeting = null;
if(hours>=1 && hours<=12){
    greeting = "Good Morning";
} else if(hours>=12 && hours<=16){
    greeting = "Good Afternoon";
} else if(hours>=16 && hours<=21){
    greeting = "Good Evening";
} else if(hours>=21 && hours<=24){
    greeting = "Good Night";
}
Toast.makeText(this, greeting, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 6):

## java.time

I would advise to use Java 8 LocalTime.

Maybe create a class like this to handle your time of day problem.

```
public class GreetingMaker { // think of a better name then this.

  private static final LocalTime MORNING = LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0);
  private static final LocalTime AFTER_NOON = LocalTime.of(12, 0, 0);
  private static final LocalTime EVENING = LocalTime.of(16, 0, 0);
  private static final LocalTime NIGHT = LocalTime.of(21, 0, 0);

  private LocalTime now;

  public GreetingMaker(LocalTime now) {
    this.now = now;
  }

  public void printTimeOfDay() { // or return String in your case
    if (between(MORNING, AFTER_NOON)) {
      System.out.println("Good Morning");
    } else if (between(AFTER_NOON, EVENING)) {
      System.out.println("Good Afternoon");
    } else if (between(EVENING, NIGHT)) {
      System.out.println("Good Evening");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Good Night");
    }
  }

  private boolean between(LocalTime start, LocalTime end) {
    return (!now.isBefore(start)) && now.isBefore(end);
  }

}
```

Comment: That first clause in your `between` test predicate should be `( ! now.isBefore( start ) )` to handle the moment when now *is* `start`.

Comment: Not sure if technically required, but I would put parens around that first clause to be safe and to be clear regarding the effect of the `NOT` “!”.

Answer (score 3):

try this code(get hours and get minute methods in Date class are deprecated.)

```
 private void getTimeFromAndroid() {
    Date dt = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(dt);
    int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    if(hours>=1 && hours<=12){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Good Morning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if(hours>=12 && hours<=16){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Good Afternoon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if(hours>=16 && hours<=21){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Good Evening", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if(hours>=21 && hours<=24){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Good Night", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You determine if it is in the first interval, and then all other intervals depends on the upper limit. So you can make it even shorter:

```
String greeting = null;
if(hours>=1 && hours<=11){
    greeting = "Good Morning";
} else if(hours<=15){
    greeting = "Good Afternoon";
} else if(hours<=20){
    greeting = "Good Evening";
} else if(hours<=24){
    greeting = "Good Night";
}
Toast.makeText(this, greeting, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Do you want at 12:59 a good morning or Good afternoon? You need to test @Devrath before accepting the answer.

Comment: @ almas shaikh .... can you edit your answer for optimization as `user987339` suggested ? ........ @ [+1] for `user987339` for optimization

Comment: @ almas sheikh you were right. I've updated the answer for case of 12:59

Comment: Well, it is not nice, that I won't get any greeting if `hours` is `0`.

Comment: Please read this [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getHours%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

Using [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) (or Time4A on Android) enables following solutions which do not need any if-else-statements:

```
ChronoFormatter<PlainTime> parser =
    ChronoFormatter.ofTimePattern("hh:mm a", PatternType.CLDR, Locale.ENGLISH);
PlainTime time = parser.parse("10:05 AM");

Map<PlainTime, String> table = new HashMap<>();
table.put(PlainTime.of(1), "Good Morning");
table.put(PlainTime.of(12), "Good Afternoon");
table.put(PlainTime.of(16), "Good Evening");
table.put(PlainTime.of(21), "Good Night");
ChronoFormatter<PlainTime> customPrinter=
    ChronoFormatter
      .setUp(PlainTime.axis(), Locale.ENGLISH)
      .addDayPeriod(table)
      .build();
System.out.println(customPrinter.format(time)); // Good Morning
```

There is also another pattern-based way to let the locale decide in a standard way based on CLDR-data how to format the clock time:

```
ChronoFormatter<PlainTime> parser =
    ChronoFormatter.ofTimePattern("hh:mm a", PatternType.CLDR, Locale.ENGLISH);
PlainTime time = parser.parse("10:05 AM");

ChronoFormatter<PlainTime> printer1 =
    ChronoFormatter.ofTimePattern("hh:mm B", PatternType.CLDR, Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(printer1.format(time)); // 10:05 in the morning

ChronoFormatter<PlainTime> printer2 =
    ChronoFormatter.ofTimePattern("B", PatternType.CLDR, Locale.ENGLISH)
        .with(Attributes.OUTPUT_CONTEXT, OutputContext.STANDALONE);
System.out.println(printer2.format(time)); // morning
```

The only other library known to me which can also do this (but in an awkward way) is ICU4J.

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner method for detecting date would be.

```
//the time cannot go below zero, so if this case is true, it must be between 0 and 12
   if(time <= 12)
   {
       return "Good Morning";
       //it will only fall into this case if the time is greater than 12.
   }else if(time < 16)
   {
       return "Good Afternoon";
   }else if(time < 21)
   {
       return "Good Evening";
   }else //it is guaranteed that the time will not exceed 24
       //, and if the previous case are all false, it must be within 21 and 24
   {
       return "Good Night";
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

For Kotlin Users They can use it like this :

```
private fun showDayMessage():String {
    val c: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    var message:String ?=null
    val timeOfDay: Int = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
    if (timeOfDay >= 0 && timeOfDay < 12) {
        message =  "Good Morning"
    } else if (timeOfDay >= 12 && timeOfDay < 16) {
        message =  "Good Afternoon"
    } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 && timeOfDay < 21) {
        message =  "Good Evening"
    } else if (timeOfDay >= 21 && timeOfDay < 24) {
        message =  "Good Night"
    }
    return  message!!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can equally have a class that returns the greetings.

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Greetings {
    public static String getGreetings()
    {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        if(timeOfDay < 12){
            return "Good morning";
        }else if(timeOfDay < 16){
            return "Good afternoon";
        }else if(timeOfDay < 21){
            return "Good evening";
        }else {
            return "Good night";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Comment: The removal of the greater than parts make this look very similar to the solution by Jianqing GAO.

Answer (score 0):

When I write

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

I didn't get output and it doesn't show any error. Just the `timeOfDay` won't get assigned any value in the code. I felt it was because of some threading while `Calendar.getInstance()` is executed. But when I collapsed the lines it worked for me. See the following code:

```
int timeOfDay = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

if(timeOfDay >= 0 && timeOfDay < 12){
        greeting.setText("Good Morning");
}else if(timeOfDay >= 12 && timeOfDay < 16){
        greeting.setText("Good Afternoon");
}else if(timeOfDay >= 16 && timeOfDay < 21){
        greeting.setText("Good Evening");
}else if(timeOfDay >= 21 && timeOfDay < 24){
        greeting.setText("Good Morning");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private String getStringFromMilli(long millis) {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(millis);
    int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

    if(hours >= 1 && hours <= 12){
        return "MORNING";
    }else if(hours >= 12 && hours <= 16){
        return "AFTERNOON";
    }else if(hours >= 16 && hours <= 21){
        return "EVENING";
    }else if(hours >= 21 && hours <= 24){
        return "NIGHT";
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If somebody looking the same for Dart and Flutter: the code without if statements - easy to read and edit.

```
main() {
  int hourValue = DateTime.now().hour;
  print(checkDayPeriod(hourValue));
}

String checkDayPeriod(int hour) {
  int _res = 21;
  Map<int, String> dayPeriods = {
    0: 'Good night',
    12: 'Good morning',
    16: 'Good afternoon',
    21: 'Good evening',
  };

  dayPeriods.forEach(
    (key, value) {
      if (hour < key && key <= _res) _res = key;
    },
  );

  return dayPeriods[_res];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace PF_Claas_Assign1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime Greeting = DateTime.Now;

            if (Greeting.Hour >= 5 && Greeting.Hour < 12)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good morning....!");
            }
            else if (Greeting.Hour >= 12 && Greeting.Hour < 16)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good afternoon...!");
            }
            else if (Greeting.Hour >= 16 && Greeting.Hour < 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good evening...!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good night...!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this better than the other answers? Not to mention that it doesn't implement the times of the question.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. The question was tagged java, this means that a Java solution is asked for. Is yours C#? Also you’re not answering the question. It was: *Is this this best way of doing it? If no, which is the best way?*

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin use the following

```
fun getCurrentTime(dateFormatInPut:String,myDate:String): Time {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatInPut, Locale.ENGLISH)
        val date = sdf.parse(myDate)
        val millis = date!!.time
        val calendar=Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.timeInMillis=millis
        return when (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) {
            in 0..11 -> Time.Morning
            in 12..15 -> Time.AfterNoon
            else -> Time.Evening
        }

    }
```

Here Time is enum class

```
enum class Time {
Morning,
AfterNoon,
Evening
```

}

Answer (score 0):

More specific

```
public static String getDayMessage() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

    if (timeOfDay < 5) {
        return "Hi, Good Mid Night";
    }else if (timeOfDay < 6) {
        return "Hi, Good Late Night";
    } else if (timeOfDay < 12) {
        return "Hi, Good Morning";
    } else if (timeOfDay < 14) {
        return "Hi, Good Noon";
    } else if (timeOfDay < 16) {
        return "Hi, Good Afternoon";
    } else if (timeOfDay < 21) {
        return "Hi, Good Evening";
    } else {
        return "Hi, Good Night";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your approach has already been covered by Answers posted months ago. If yours is an improvement, edit to describe that improvement. If not, I suggest you delete the Answer.

Comment: This code uses the *terrible* `Calendar` class that was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. See the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46379428/642706) by Nahar.

Answer (score 0):

As Simple as possible

```
 private String getTimeFromAndroid() {
            Date dt = new Date();
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(dt);
            int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    
            if(hours<=12){       
                return "Good Morning";
            }else if(hours<=16){        
                return "Good Afternoon";        
            }else if(hours<=21){         
                return "Good Evening";        
            }else {
                return "Good Night";
            }              
        }
```

Comment: It would be still simpler with `LocalTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).  Your code is as old-fashioned as possible.

Comment: Also is there anything substantial here that isn’t already covered by the answers by donnicias and by Jianqing GAO?

Answer (score 0):

This solution seems perfect for the **tropics** area countries' users. Suppose my country is Bangladesh and this greeting is appropriate for our users most of the time.

```
 public static String getTimeToHumanGenericTerm(boolean isBangla, Calendar c) {
        int timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        if (timeOfDay < 5) {
            return isBangla ? " মধ্যরাত " : " Mid Night";
        } else if (timeOfDay < 6) {
            return isBangla ? " শেষরাত " : " Late Night";
        } else if (timeOfDay < 12) {
            return isBangla ? " সকাল  " : " Late Night";
        } else if (timeOfDay < 14) {
            return isBangla ? " দুপুর" : " Noon";
        } else if (timeOfDay < 16) {
            return isBangla ? " বিকাল" : " Afternoon";
        } else if (timeOfDay < 21) {
            return isBangla ? " সন্ধ্যা" : " Evening";
        } else {
            return isBangla ? " রাত " : " Night";
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalTime` or some other class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

I am developing an app in Bengali language for the people of my country, there I have written the code to detect morning, noon, afternoon, evening and night.

**My code in Kotlin:**

```
val c = Calendar.getInstance()
val time = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
            
            timeState = if (time < 13) "সকালবেলা" // Morning
            else if (time < 15) "দুপুরবেলা" // noon
            else if (time < 18) "বিকেলবেলা" // afternoon
            else if (time < 20) "সন্ধ্যাবেলা" // evening
            else "রাত্রিবেলা" // night
```

**My code in Java:**

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int time = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        // Set the time state
        String timeState;
        if (time < 13) timeState = "সকালবেলা"; // Morning
        else if (time < 15) timeState = "দুপুরবেলা"; // noon
        else if (time < 18) timeState = "বিকেলবেলা"; // afternoon
        else if (time < 20) timeState = "সন্ধ্যাবেলা"; // evening
        else timeState = "রাত্রিবেলা"; // night
```

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for your response, I have updated my answer.

Comment: The `Calendar` class is a terrible mess, and is now [legacy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system). Use only *java.time* classes, defined in JSR 310.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes, you are correct. But for now I am not using 'time' class as my project's 'minSdk' is too  low.

Comment: For Java 6 & 7, use *ThreeTen-Backport* library.

Comment: For earlier Android, the latest tooling provides access to much of the *java.time* classes via “API desugaring”.

Comment: @BasilBourque, Wow! great answare. Actually I didn't know about 'API desugaring' before.
thank you