# Current time and range

Tags: java, android

I want to get the current time and compare that with time range provided by me.
for example I want to set the greeting message of Good morning if the current time is between 6:00 AM to 11:59 AM

Here is some code of my android Application

```
import java.text.DateFormat; 
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; 
import java.util.Calendar; 
import java.util.Date; 
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    protected Calendar firstBound;
    protected Calendar secondBound;
    protected static Calendar cal;
    protected static String timeString = null;
    protected static String greetString = null;
    protected static DateFormat date;
    Button greetButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get a reference to the greetButton on the UI
        greetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.greetButton);
        cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());

        Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        timeString = date.format(currentLocalTime);
        char h1 = timeString.charAt(0);
        char h2 = timeString.charAt(1);
        char m1 = timeString.charAt(3);
        char m2 = timeString.charAt(4);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR,Character.getNumericValue(h1) + Character.getNumericValue(h2));
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Character.getNumericValue(m1) + Character.getNumericValue(m2));
        // Set the onClickListener for the greetButton to be this class.
        // This requires that the class implement the View.OnClickListener callback
        // the onClick() method
        greetButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

And My On Click method is

```
public void onClick(View v) {       
    TextView textMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textMessage);
    EditText editFriendName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFriendName);       
    String friendName = editFriendName.getText().toString();
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.greetButton:
            // set the string being displayed by the TextView to the greeting
            if(cal.after(setFirstBoundLimits(14, 00)) && cal.before(setSecondBoundLimits(18, 00))){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, timeString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            // message for the friend
            //textMessage.setText(getString(R.string.greetstring) + friendName + "!");
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
}
private Calendar setFirstBoundLimits(int hh, int mm){
    firstBound = Calendar.getInstance();
    firstBound.set(Calendar.HOUR, hh);
    firstBound.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mm);
    return firstBound;
}
```

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem is. You've provided some code but no context. i.e. What is currently working/not working as you expect it to?

Comment: oops sorry @deyur...Here the problem was, the If statement in void click()method was not working...i.e I want to show good Morning , Good Afternoon message based on comparision made by If construct..But finally i got help from the link below

Comment: By the way thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Period and Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html)

[Smart Hello](http://my.hsonline.net/~rrosetta/Java/javatutorial.htm)

[Showing Morning, afternoon, evening, night message based on Time in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589701/showing-morning-afternoon-evening-night-message-based-on-time-in-java)

[Difference in days between two dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299972/difference-in-days-between-two-dates-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

****Thank you...this code really worked for me

---

```
 protected String getCurrentTimeMessage(){
    //Date date = new Date();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    //cal.setTime(date);
    int hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    if(hours>=6 && hours<=11){
      //Toast.makeText(this, "Good Morning" + hours, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return "Good Morning";
    }else if(hours>=12 && hours<=16){
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Good Afternoon"+ hours, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return "Good Afternoon";
    }else if(hours>=17 && hours<=20){
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Good Evening"+ hours, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return "Good Evening";
    }else if(hours>=21 && hours<=23){
      //  Toast.makeText(this, "Good Night"+ hours, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return "Good Night";
    }
    else if(hours >=0 && hours <= 5){
        return "Good Night";
    }

    return null;
}
```