# Outputting the day period based on locale

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I want to format a date, which should be localized and includes the "day period".

"Day period" meaning not am/pm but "afternoon", "early morning" etc.

A formatted date based on german locale with the 12 hour setting enabled should look like `03.08.18, 9:01 abends`, "abends" meaning evening.

The same example should be `3/8/18 9:01 de la noche` in spanish.

---

**Why i think it should be possible**:

A: Because the WhatsApp Android app formats dates like this

B: Because the Java 10 source code includes the following (From the german translation file):

```
<dayPeriods>
<dayPeriodContext type="format">
    <dayPeriodWidth type="wide">
        <dayPeriod type="afternoon">nachmittags</dayPeriod>
        <dayPeriod type="am">vorm.</dayPeriod>
        <dayPeriod type="earlyMorning">morgens</dayPeriod>
        <dayPeriod type="evening">abends</dayPeriod>
        <dayPeriod type="morning">vormittags</dayPeriod>
        <dayPeriod type="night">nachts</dayPeriod>
        <dayPeriod type="noon">Mittag</dayPeriod>
        <dayPeriod type="pm">nachm.</dayPeriod>
    </dayPeriodWidth>
</dayPeriodContext>
...
</dayPeriods>
```

---

**I tried**: (current is the locale)

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT, current);

String formattedDate = df.format(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Output: `08.12.18 7:24 nachm` or `8/12/18 7:54 p. m.`

---

The following code has the same output:

```
DateFormat abc = SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT, current);

abc.format(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

---

I also tried the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` (With all of the AMPM_OF_DAY versions):

```
DateTimeFormatter test = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM, FormatStyle.SHORT);

DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .append(test)
                .appendText(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, TextStyle.SHORT)
                .appendText(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, TextStyle.NARROW)
                .appendText(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, TextStyle.FULL)
                .appendText(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE)
                .toFormatter(current);

ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.now();
date.format(fmt);
```

Output: `8 dic. 2018 19:54p. m.p. m.p. m.11`

---

Is there any way i can output the date this way?

Thanks

Comment: A basic problem may be that different cultures divide the day differently, so there is no direct translation. You already got a bit of this in AM and PM, which aren’t used in German. It’s not something I know, but I imagine that people around the mediterranean would expect a “siesta” time of day that is not in your list. And so on and so forth.

Comment: You should certainly prefer the modern `DateTimeFormatter` over the troublesome and old-fashioned `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for your thoughts. Yes that is a problem. I would like to know how WhatsApp does it. I think they just use the right java date formatter or a little trick, because all necessary information is in the java source. The [Unicode LDML](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#dayPeriods) specifies the periods. LDML is the spec java uses for the locales

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing Morning, afternoon, evening, night message based on Time in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589701/showing-morning-afternoon-evening-night-message-based-on-time-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only two libraries which support day periods, namely ICU4J (partially incorporated in Android) and my lib Time4A. Other formatters like `java.text.DateFormat` or `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` have no support.

Example in [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A) for the German locale (here with a bridge to the old-fashioned type `java.util.Date`):

```
 ChronoFormatter<java.util.Date> f =
      ChronoFormatter.ofPattern(
          "dd.MM.uuuu, h:mm BBBB",
          PatternType.CLDR,
          Locale.GERMAN,
          Moment.axis(TemporalType.JAVA_UTIL_DATE))
      .withStdTimezone();
 System.out.println(f.format(new java.util.Date()));
```

example output => "11.12.2018, 6:03 morgens"

It uses the [special pattern symbol "B"](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/format/expert/PatternType.html#CLDR) defined by LDML-syntax of CLDR-data (managed by Unicode consortium). The day partition rules are also taken from CLDR data and look for German like:

```
# day-period-rules
T0000=night1
T0500=morning1
T1000=morning2
T1200=afternoon1
T1300=afternoon2
T1800=evening1

# day-period-translations
P(a)_morning1=morgens
P(a)_morning2=vormittags
P(a)_afternoon1=mittags
P(a)_afternoon2=nachmittags
P(a)_evening1=abends
P(a)_night1=nachts
```

If you don't agree with these data then you might construct your own customized formatter via the [builder pattern](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/format/expert/ChronoFormatter.Builder.html#addDayPeriod-java.util.Map-).

Note about ICU4J: I have not tested that lib but maybe its class `com.ibm.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat` supports the pattern symbol B, too (but then the javadoc is outdated).

Another note:

If you like style-based formatting without specifying a concrete pattern then you might go this way using a composition of date and time part:

```
    Locale loc = Locale.US;

    // our concrete values to be formatted
    Moment moment = SystemClock.currentMoment();
    PlainDate calendarDate = moment.toLocalTimestamp().getCalendarDate();

    // get the localized clock pattern
    Map<String, String> textForms = CalendarText.getIsoInstance(loc).getTextForms();
    String pattern = 
            textForms.containsKey("F_Bhm") ? textForms.get("F_Bhm") : "h:mm B";

    // construct the style-based date formatter
    ChronoFormatter<PlainDate> f1 = 
            ChronoFormatter.ofDateStyle(DisplayMode.SHORT, loc);

    // construct the time formatter
    ChronoFormatter<Moment> f2 = ChronoFormatter.ofMomentPattern(
        pattern,
        PatternType.CLDR,
        loc,
        Timezone.ofSystem().getID());

    System.out.println(f1.format(calendarDate) + " " + f2.format(moment));
    // example output => "12/11/18 6:18 in the morning"
```

Comment: This was already very helpful. Is there any way to get the date and time pattern like the `DateUtils.formatDateTime` outputs? SimpleDateFormat and your examples are missing the ", " (` 12.12.2018, 1:13 nachm.`), which i unfortunately need based on locale (Some locales include it and some dont).

Comment: @Nick I understand your desire for localized literals combining date and time patterns. Unfortunately Time4J/A does not yet support it. But I have opened a [new issue](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J/issues/845) to track any suggestions/proposals. Your proposals are welcome. To be realistic, due to the complexity, a final solution will not be present before spring 2019.

Answer (score 0):

The day period support is there now with Java 16. The new formatter symbol "B" gives this support.

Example -

```
ZonedDateTime utcDateZoned = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
System.out.println(utcDateZoned.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd:mm:yyy-h:mm B").withLocale(Locale.UK)));
System.out.println(utcDateZoned.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd:mm:yyy-h:mm B").withLocale(Locale.CHINA)));
System.out.println(utcDateZoned.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd:mm:yyy-h:mm B").withLocale(Locale.ITALY)));
System.out.println(utcDateZoned.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd:mm:yyy-h:mm B").withLocale(Locale.GERMAN)));
```

Output -

06:26:2023-4:26 in the afternoon

06:26:2023-4:26 下午

06:26:2023-4:26 del pomeriggio

06:26:2023-4:26 nachmittags